# Remote images on Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, geoserver

I am using Glassfish v3.1 for a Java web application, which gets data from other servers as well. One of these servers is running Geoserver GIS. I can only have the Glassfish server on a public IP.

In order to load a map image, I can call from the JSF pages or any HTML page something like:

> http://10.10.10.10:1234/map/query?someparameters&format=image/jpeg

which returns a jpeg image.

If I hardcode this into the pages, it works fine locally (i.e. when 10.10.10.10 is accessible by the browser) but of course fails remotely.

Other than grabbing the image as a file/stream through a bean and then serving it to the server, is there a simpler way to serve these images through the web server? Ideally using Glassfish as some kind of proxy that pushes all request for say http://myserver.com/map to http://10.10.10.10:1234?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP Proxy Servlet](http://edwardstx.net/2010/06/http-proxy-servlet/) looks like it will do what you are looking for.  There are likely to be other methods (like putting GF and the geoserver behind an Apache server and using mod_proxy) that would work, too.